# Ubuntu 14.04 + Bumblebee, Unable to control Brightness and have Bumblebee working at the same time

Tags: nvidia, brightness, bumblebee, hybrid-graphics

I'm current running Ubuntu 14.04 with a GTX 780m gpu on my laptop and using nvidia-331 drivers with bumblebee.

I was unable to control the brightness of my screen, but then I decided to follow some tips on the internet and added the following lines to the file **/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf**:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "card0"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

After that I was able to control the brightness, all fine and dandy. The problem is that, after that, bumblebee doesn't work, for example, trying to open Steam by using primusrun gives this message:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1409240101_client)
primus: fatal: Bumblebee daemon reported: error: [XORG] (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.

[2014-09-24 21:08:10] Startup - updater built Aug 28 2014 03:23:49
Installing bootstrap /home/cabeca/.local/share/Steam/bootstrap.tar.xz
Reset complete!
Restarting Steam by request...
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME has been set by the user to: /home/cabeca/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1409240101_client)
primus: fatal: Bumblebee daemon reported: error: [XORG] (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.

ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
[2014-09-24 21:08:15] Startup - updater built Aug 26 2014 15:35:42
```

If I try optirun steam, that's what appears:

```
[ 6051.673074] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.

[ 6051.673179] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

Looking over the Internet, someone pointed out that, by adding this code:

```
Section "Screen"

    Identifier "Default Screen"

    Device "DiscreteNvidia"

EndSection
```

To the head of the file **/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia** would work, but it didn't. After applying this modifications, when I try **primusrun steam**, that's what I get:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1411443970)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1411443970)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1411443970)
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"

(steam:21527): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",

(steam:21527): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
/usr/share/themes/Orchis/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:1137: error: unexpected identifier `direction', expected character `}'
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"

(steamwebhelper:21549): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",

(steamwebhelper:21549): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
/usr/share/themes/Orchis/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:1137: error: unexpected identifier `direction', expected character `}'
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20140922201705)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1411417025)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20140922201705)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1411417025)
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
[0924/211753:ERROR:nss_util.cc(1018)] Failed to load NSS libraries.
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1411443970)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1411443970)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1411443970)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1411443970)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1411443970)
[0924/211753:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(227)] Running without renderer sandbox
[0924/211753:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(227)] Running without renderer sandbox
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
primus: fatal: failed to acquire direct rendering context for display thread
Assert( Assertion Failed: Bad thread local ):/home/buildbot/buildslave_steam/steam_rel_client_ubuntu12_linux/build/src/tier0/threadtools.cpp:2671

Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1411443970)
Uploading dump (out-of-process) [proxy '']
/tmp/dumps/assert_20140924211754_10.dmp
/home/buildbot/buildslave_steam/steam_rel_client_ubuntu12_linux/build/src/clientdll/../common/steamservice.cpp (54) : Assertion Failed: m_hServiceLib == NULL
Assert( Assertion Failed: m_hServiceLib == NULL ):/home/buildbot/buildslave_steam/steam_rel_client_ubuntu12_linux/build/src/clientdll/../common/steamservice.cpp:54

Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1411443970)
Uploading dump (out-of-process) [proxy '']
/tmp/dumps/crash_20140924211754_12.dmp
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
Uploading dump (out-of-process) [proxy '']
/tmp/dumps/assert_20140924211751_1.dmp
/home/cabeca/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 729: 21527 Segmentation fault      $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
Requested Force create but SharedObjectMutex already created
Forced create but already created for SharedObjectEvent
Forced create but already created for SharedObjectEvent
Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
response: CrashID=bp-0337ce69-7d86-40c6-8e26-2dd562140924
Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
response: CrashID=bp-14f176ea-917c-45e7-914e-7e8292140924
Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
response: CrashID=bp-6464b83a-8099-41ff-9416-6bdb52140924
```

And **optirun steam**:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1411443970)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1411443970)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1411443970)
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"

(steam:22013): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",

(steam:22013): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
/usr/share/themes/Orchis/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:1137: error: unexpected identifier `direction', expected character `}'
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"

(steamwebhelper:22069): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",

(steamwebhelper:22069): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
/usr/share/themes/Orchis/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:1137: error: unexpected identifier `direction', expected character `}'
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20140922201705)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1411417025)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20140922201705)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1411417025)
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
[0924/212102:ERROR:nss_util.cc(1018)] Failed to load NSS libraries.
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1411443970)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1411443970)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1411443970)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1411443970)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1411443970)
[0924/212103:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(227)] Running without renderer sandbox
[0924/212103:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(227)] Running without renderer sandbox
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
primus: fatal: failed to acquire direct rendering context for display thread
Assert( Assertion Failed: Bad thread local ):/home/buildbot/buildslave_steam/steam_rel_client_ubuntu12_linux/build/src/tier0/threadtools.cpp:2671

Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1411443970)
Uploading dump (out-of-process) [proxy '']
/tmp/dumps/assert_20140924212103_10.dmp
/home/buildbot/buildslave_steam/steam_rel_client_ubuntu12_linux/build/src/clientdll/../common/steamservice.cpp (54) : Assertion Failed: m_hServiceLib == NULL
Assert( Assertion Failed: m_hServiceLib == NULL ):/home/buildbot/buildslave_steam/steam_rel_client_ubuntu12_linux/build/src/clientdll/../common/steamservice.cpp:54

Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1411443970)
Uploading dump (out-of-process) [proxy '']
/tmp/dumps/crash_20140924212104_12.dmp
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
Uploading dump (out-of-process) [proxy '']
/tmp/dumps/assert_20140924212100_1.dmp
/home/cabeca/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 729: 22013 Segmentation fault      $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
Requested Force create but SharedObjectMutex already created
Forced create but already created for SharedObjectEvent
Forced create but already created for SharedObjectEvent
Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
response: CrashID=bp-9d3792c9-ea19-470b-866f-3c1152140924
Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
response: CrashID=bp-c98bd198-6010-477d-84aa-017282140924
Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
response: CrashID=bp-d1f0996b-3068-4766-9534-e5ffe2140924
```

So, do you have any idea about how can I have both my brightness control and bumblebee working?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm having a similar "failed to acquire direct rendering context" problem, too; see [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/slackware-current-kernel-3-14-16-and-nvidia-optimus-4175514098/#post5224966).

Comment: Dec. 14, 2014, patch pertaining to the "failed to acquire direct rendering context" issue: http://pastebin.com/fJTtpHGU

Comment: So, is it working now?
Thx!